# The chemical poet

Tags: steganography

So the other day I was doing my Chemistry Test and I was sitting near the cleverest kid in class. I asked him about this question I was bummed over and then he sang out:

> Ello! Nice the moon today. 
>   Why is Knockturn India pleating extra decks in all? 
>   The Wazir of Ireland kills Icelandish thanes, 
>   Who India killed in the offs. 
>   Xiana! Yo! God enters neatly.

He was asked to leave the hall. What was he trying to tell me?

*Hint:*

> If you take the last line as "Xiana! Yo! God enter, neatly through!", the intended meaning will be the same. Think of it? What is the same, even if you add a new character to it?

*Added Hint:*

> Don't drink tea. Drinking tea won't let you solve it.

-By the way, please add a few more tags if needed.-

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen
>
> Taking the first letter of every word gives:
> EN TMT WIKIPEDIA TWOIKI T WIKI T OXYGEN
> I'm not sure how 'TMT' becomes '.' or TWOIKI becomes '.org' though the letter T can be swapped out for the forward slash.
> EN /M/ WIKIPEDIA /WOIKI / WIKI / OXYGEN

Comment: Maybe it's the mobile site (en.m.wikipedia.org)

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> Taking the first letters gives:
> ENITMT
> WIKIPEDIA
> TWOIKIT
> WIKITO
> XYGEN(T)
> I can see "OXYGEN" in there at the end, and of course "WIKIPEDIA", but I'm not sure what to do with those or how the other letters are relevant.

Comment: keep it coming... you're almost there...

Comment: 'ctually you got the answer, you just don't know how you got it.

Comment: @AravindSuresh: How was I supposed to know to remove Ts? There was *nothing* indicating that in the original post.